# Postgresql cannot find file name specified in copy command

Tags: postgresql, windows-7-x64

I try this:

```
COPY gemeenten 
  FROM 'D:\CBS_woningcijfers_2014.csv'
  DELIMITER ';' CSV
```

and get this:

```
ERROR:  could not open file "D:\CBS_woningcijfers_2014.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
```

I doubled the backslashes, tried an E string, replaced \ by /, used " instead of ' but now I've run out of options. I am sure the file exists. Anybody any idea?

Comment: Is your file on the same machine as your PostgreSQL instance?

Comment: On an unrelated matter is the delimiter a semicolon or is it a CSV file?  The answer/comment @Nicarus gave is the most likely issue.

Answer (score 7):

If the file and the PostgreSQL database are on the same machine, then the path and/or name of the file are not correct.

If the file is on your local machine and the database is on another, you cannot use the `COPY` command in SQL. You have two main choices to make this work:

**1)** Use `psql \copy` from your local machine. The syntax is similar, but it will transfer from your local to the remote. The docs are pretty helpful: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY

**2)** Upload the file to the remote machine and then execute your command. Just make sure you are referencing the correct path and filename.

Comment: Good answer. I've posted a patch to the PostgreSQL mailing list to help users out with this, since this is far from the first time I've seen it. Hopefully it'll get into PostgreSQL 10.0; it's too late for 9.6 now. Link: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMsr+YEqtD97qPEzQDqrCt5QiqPbWP_X4hmvy2pQzWC0GWiyPA@mail.gmail.com